# PHP login in one domain then using the session in another one

Tags: php, session

So I have this variable I must send to another website. How can I send it in a way that user can't change it? It like an account id, for a login session, since the user logs in through Steam, he doesn't need to enter a password(at least on the site). I need to pass his account id to another domain securely. By securely I mean, I don't care if he sees it as long as he can't change it no matter what. is there any way of doing this?
The reason I can't let them log in directly in the first website is because steam has flagged it, like it did to a lot of sites that has ref codes. So the user is kinda not able to log in cause in the warning the "continue anyways" button is so tiny that many users don't even see it. So I made like big sites did, bought another domain and redirected the login to it. This other site is not blacklisted so the login can go normally.

Answer (score 1):

That issue seems a bit challenging,  I mean I would do it through an api request. Got to be that way. Probably somebody spices that task a bit more

But that is the way to communicate between two domains, via curl calls and therefore you need TO BUild an api for it. The redirection is an issue there probably via js-ajax.

[Edit] Redirect users to the second site (php Header), once in the second site, do the login, that is, authenticate and populate the session variable through curl requests to the first site

Comment: I thought about sending a post request with the account id to the index of the first website and then setting the session. But I'm not sure if it's secure or if the user can manipulate the data

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using CURL to authenticate and get a response back from the authenticating domain to use on the origin domain.

> **origin.com/authenticate-user.php**
>
> ```
> $ch = curl_init('http://authenticator.com/authenticate-user.php');
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('steam_id' => $_SESSION['steam_id'])));
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
> $response = curl_exec($ch);
> curl_close ($ch);
> $_SESSION['user_valid'] = $response;
> ```

> **authenticator.com/authenticate-user.php**
>
> ```
> //optional conditions to test origin or requesting source to prevent cross-site attacks.
> if (isset($_POST['steam_id']){
>      //..validate user here
>      echo 1;
> } else {
>      echo 0;
> }
> ```

This would make the request sent by your server instead of the client, and unchangeable by the user. It will also only require you to manage a session from one domain instead of two, since all the authenticator does is process the information sent to it.
Not sure why a session would need to be set on the authenticating domain though, if you can give a scenario it would be needed.
You can also change the response to anything you like, serving the entire webpage if desired.

---

Another option is to use cookies as opposed to sessions.
Cookies can be shared cross-domain by allowing it within your API processor via `CORS` and an `XMLHttpRequest` (ajax).
But anything being sent via `XMLHttpRequest` can be stopped and manipulated by the user.

- CORS PHP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control
- Example: http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/credentialedRequest.html

Comment: I didn't understand quite well the first option, would origin.com be the main site which is blacklisted on steam?

Comment: Yes, and all the non-blacklisted domain does is forward the request to steam, responding back with whatever you like. You can even send the entire text, json, xml, html response back to the blacklisted site to process. Effectively acting as a proxy.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that on the steam login system. Do you know how the system works? When u click on login button you are redirected to steam, and after you log in you are redirected to your website. The steam warning is shown upon the click of the login button. So I don't think this would work

Comment: I am familiar with the steam web API and OpenID and have in the past created a personal Wordpress plugin to allow website members to sign in with their steam accounts and import their profile data. CURL was used to facilitate the button press and profile/game data retrieval.

Comment: So, your code above will not solve my problem since is when the user clicks on "login" that the problem occurs... But I was thinking, what if I use curl to post the account id from the not-blacklisted website to the main one, would the user be able to intercept and change it?

Comment: The code is applicable in either direction. CURL uses the Server to transmit data between your Servers, and not the client. Because of this the client is unable to manipulate the data between them. It's up to you to facilitate the responses on either side how you need, but only a single session state on the blacklisted website is needed to maintain the client state.

Comment: I just realized that in this way it wont work too. I mean, I'm only sending a post, the user wont be redirected to the main website, or will him?